# How to create regex to extract some html elements from document

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am new to make regex and I want to know how to make a perfect regex that can do exactly its job.

This is an example:

I want to extract all elements that match this one from HTML document

```
<span class="st">
    <em>Echo</em> Reservoir, <em>UT</em>, 
    local weather including current conditions, extended forecasts,
    alerts, <em>Utah</em> weather map and more.
</span>
```

and want to bring text only sometimes. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: regex + html is never a good combination

Comment: Which language? Please pick one...  "Want to bring text only sometimes" means what?

Comment: Not PHP or javascript ?

Comment: Is there a visual basic HTML parsing library you suggest Jaromanda X ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+html

Comment: PHP if possible Tim.

Comment: I've answered your question but you should really clear up what language you are asking for and clarify what you need to extract from the HTML.

Comment: Why I am getting downvotes?

Comment: I think regex is one for all languages ?

Comment: Is this for visual basic or PHP?

Comment: @MohamedHana why have you specified PHP, VB *and* Javascript? Specify just one.

Comment: OK Dean for visual basic

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons not to use regex to parse and extract things from HTML but I'll leave it to bobince to explain them: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

It would be better to use a dedicated HTML parser to perform the task. A quick Google search suggests [PHP HTML Parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser) for PHP which also includes several examples.

If you're using VB.NET then use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks Dean, I will give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Simple HTML DOM on numerous PHP projects. It will do exactly what you want.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net